# What is the historical context for long and int often being the same size?

Tags: c, size, history, int, long-integer

According to [numerous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=long+size) here, `long` and `int` are both 32 bits in size on common platforms in C and C++ (Windows & Linux, 32 & 64 bit.) (I'm aware that there is no standard, but in practice, these are the observed sizes.)

So my question is, how did this come about? Why do we have two types that are the same size? I previously always assumed `long` would be 64 bits most of the time, and `int` 32. I'm not saying it "should" be one way or the other, I'm just curious as to how we got here.

Comment: In my experiences with GCC sizeof( int ) returns 4 where as sizeof( long ) returns 8 ...

Comment: it's actually an open question in the spec, as long as the inequality I have in my answer holds.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_integer) explains that - 64-bit UNIX implementations of long tend to be 8 bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [C99 rationale (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) on section 6.2.5:

> [...] In the 1970s, 16-bit C (for the
>   PDP-11) first represented file
>   information with 16-bit integers,
>   which were rapidly obsoleted by disk
>   progress. People switched to a 32-bit
>   file system, first using `int[2]`
>   constructs which were not only
>   awkward, but also not efficiently
>   portable to 32-bit hardware.
>
> To solve the problem, the `long` type
>   was added to the language, even though
>   this required C on the PDP-11 to
>   generate multiple operations to
>   simulate 32-bit arithmetic. Even as
>   32-bit minicomputers became available
>   alongside 16-bit systems, people still
>   used `int` for efficiency, reserving
>   `long` for cases where larger integers
>   were truly needed, since `long` was
>   noticeably less efficient on 16-bit
>   systems. Both `short` and `long` were
>   added to C, making `short` available
>   for 16 bits, `long` for 32 bits, and
>   `int` as convenient for performance.
>   There was no desire to lock the
>   numbers 16 or 32 into the language, as
>   there existed C compilers for at least
>   24- and 36-bit CPUs, but rather to
>   provide names that could be used for
>   32 bits as needed.
>
> PDP-11 C might have been
>   re-implemented with `int` as 32-bits,
>   thus avoiding the need for `long`; but
>   that would have made people change
>   most uses of `int` to `short` or
>   suffer serious performance degradation
>   on PDP-11s. In addition to the
>   potential impact on source code, the
>   impact on existing object code and
>   data files would have been worse, even
>   in 1976. By the 1990s, with an immense
>   installed base of software, and with
>   widespread use of dynamic linked
>   libraries, the impact of changing the
>   size of a common data object in an
>   existing environment is so high that
>   few people would tolerate it, although
>   it might be acceptable when creating a
>   new environment. Hence, many vendors,
>   to avoid namespace conflicts, have
>   added a 64-bit integer to their 32-bit
>   C environments using a new name, of
>   which `long long` has been the most
>   widely used. [...]

Comment: Hmm Charlie Martin's answer has the most upvotes, but this quote, directly from the horse's mouth as it were, is strong. I especially like that it describes it from a historical context (this is what existed, this is why we need to still support that), rather than saying "the standard says $X."

Comment: It's worth noting that on many older machines (and many small embedded microcontrollers even today), 16-bit numbers could be processed faster than 32-bit numbers, but on many newer machines, 32-bit numbers can actually be processed faster than 16-bit numbers.  While it's useful to be able to explicitly request 16-bit numbers in some contexts, especially arrays and structures, they should be used sparingly.  If only needs a variable to handle numbers +/-32767, it's useful to be able to request that the compiler use whatever size is most convenient to fulfill that need.

Answer (score 6):

Historically, most of the sizes and types in C can be traced back to the PDP-11 architecture.  That had bytes, words (16 bits) and doublewords (32 bits).  When C and UNIX were moved to another machine (the Interdata 832 I think), the word length was 32 bits.  To keep the source compatible, `long` and `int` were defined so that, strictly

> `sizeof(short)` ≤ `sizeof(int)` ≤ `sizeof(long)`.

Most machines now end up with `sizeof(int)` = `sizeof(long)` because 16 bits is no longer convenient, but we have long long to get 64 bits if needed.

**Update** strictly I should have said "compilers" because different compiler implmentors can make different decisions for the same instruction set architecture. GCC and Microsoft, for example.

Comment: About your update: If you're talking about `long` vs `int` with GCC on Windows, MinGW.org (32-bit) and mingw-w64 (32/64-bit) both adhere to MS ABI, which is `sizeof(int)==sizeof(long)==4`. I don't know if MSVC even supports stuff like `long double`, but that might be where there's a difference. Size of integers is often dictated on an OS/ABI level.

Comment: @Ruben, it just gets worse when you look at some of the other compilers around.  The point is that as a compiler writer you can choose pretty freely -- but that may add complexity writing against OS APIs and the like.

Answer (score 3):

Back in the late 70s and early 80s many architectures were 16 bit, so typically char was 8 bit, int was 16 bit and long was 32 bit. In the late 80s there was a general move to 32 bit architectures and so int became 32 bits but long remained at 32 bits.

Over the last 10 years there has been a move towards 64 bit computing and we now have a couple of different models, the most common being [LP64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit), where ints are still 32 bits and long is now 64 bits.

Bottom line: don't make any assumptions about the sizes of different integer types (other than what's defined in the standard of course) and if you need fixed size types then use `<stdint.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the C standard requires that a `long` be at least 32 bits long, and be at least as long as an `int`. An `int`, on the other hand, is always (I think) equal to the native word size of the architecture.

Bear in mind that, when the standards were drawn up, 32-bit machines were not common; originally, an `int` would probably have been the native 16-bits, and a `long` would have been twice as long at 32-bits.

Comment: "An int, on the other hand, is always (I think) equal to the native word size of the architecture" - it's at least 16 bits, even though some 8 bit architectures might not even *have* a "word size". There's some pretty vague language in the standard, "[int] has the natural size suggested by the architecture". Now to me, a 64 bit architecture suggests a 64 bit "natural size", but implementers of C routinely ignore that. So I conclude that the vague language is meaningless, `int` is a type by definition at least 16 bits, empirically it's typically 32, can't say much more.

Comment: In particular, if anyone rashly assumes that "natural size" or "word size" implies that `int` is the same size as a pointer, then they have another think coming. I guess that 64 bit pointers are of "unnatural size" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In 16-bit operating systems, int was 16-bit and long was 32-bit. After moving to Win32, both become 32 bit. Moving to 64 bit OS, it is a good idea to keep long size unchanged, this doesn't break existing code when it compiled in 64 bit. New types (like Microsoft-specific __int64, size_t etc.) may be used in 64 bit programs.